# Adding FlowDocument to MainWindow

Tags: c#, flowdocument

What's the best practice to add a FlowDocument you saved as an Xaml to the main window of your application.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <FlowDocumentReader Document="">
            <FlowDocument>
                <!-- I WANT TO ADD THE FLOWDOCUMENT I SAVED AS AN XAML HERE-->
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentReader>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used the example on this page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751864(v=vs.85).aspx

Xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="PrintSimpleTextButton" Content="Print Button" Width="100" Grid.Row="0" Click="PrintSimpleTextButton_Click"></Button>

        <FlowDocumentReader
            Name="flowDocRdr" 
            IsFindEnabled="True"  
            IsPrintEnabled="True"
            MinZoom="50" MaxZoom="1000"
            Zoom="100" ZoomIncrement="5"
            Grid.Row="1"
        />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code for loading the flowdocument

```
private void PrintSimpleTextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     string filename = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Dropbox\\Engineering\\Practice\\C# Xaml\\PrinterTest\\PrinterTest\\QRCodeStyleA_FlowDoc.xaml";
            FileStream xamlFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FlowDocument content = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xamlFile) as FlowDocument;
            flowDocRdr.Document = content;


        }
```